# KnockoutJs: create checkbox list based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of GeneNames that will be used for the data-bind options for the select control

```
(GeneDropdownOptions:)
["CYP2D6","CYP2C19","CYP3A4","COMT","CACNA1C","MTHFR","ANK3","5HT2C","DRD2","SLC6A4"]

<!-- ko foreach: $root.AssaySelectedGenes -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label data-bind='uniqueFor: true'>Gene:</label>
        <select class="form-control" data-bind='uniqueName: true, options: $root.GeneDropdownOptions, value: $data, optionsCaption: "Select Gene"'></select>                       
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Depending on which GeneName value is selected from the dropdown I need to be able to generate a checkbox list of Snips from this collection of key value pair data

```
(SnipCheckboxOptions:)
[{"GeneName":"CYP2D6","Snips":["CYP2D6*2","CYP2D6*3","CYP2D6*4","CYP2D6*5","CYP2D6*6","CYP2D6*9","CYP2D6*10","CYP2D6*17","CYP2D6*41"]},{"GeneName":"CYP2C19","Snips":["CYP2C19*2","CYP2C19*3","CYP2C19*17"]},{"GeneName":"CYP3A4","Snips":["CYP3A4*3","CYP3A4*6","CYP3A4*7"]},{"GeneName":"COMT","Snips":["COMT"]},{"GeneName":"CACNA1C","Snips":["CACNA1C"]},{"GeneName":"MTHFR","Snips":["MTHFR"]},{"GeneName":"ANK3","Snips":["ANK3"]},{"GeneName":"5HT2C","Snips":["5HT2C"]},{"GeneName":"DRD2","Snips":["DRD2"]},{"GeneName":"SLC6A4","Snips":["SLC6A4*1","SLC6A4*2"]}]
```

Can someone assist with this functionality by pointing me to a similar example or throwing a jsfiddle demo. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:-

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label data-bind='uniqueFor: true'>Gene:</label>
   <select class="form-control" data-bind='uniqueName: true, options: $root.GeneDropdownOptions, value: selectedGene, optionsCaption: "Select Gene"'></select>
</div>
<!-- ko foreach: snipData().Snips -->
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data,checked:$parent.checkedSnips" />
   <span  data-bind="text:$data"></span>
   <br/>
<!-- /ko -->
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(checkedSnips)"></pre>
```

Viewmodel:-

```
var Vm = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.GeneDropdownOptions = ko.observableArray(genes);
  self.selectedGene = ko.observable();
  self.SnipCheckboxOptions = ko.observableArray(snipData);
  self.checkedSnips = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.snipData = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var gene = self.selectedGene(),
        arr = [];
    self.checkedSnips.removeAll();
    if (gene && gene !== "") {
        arr = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SnipCheckboxOptions(), function (i) {
            return i.GeneName === gene;
        });
    }
    return arr || [];
  });

}
 ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M26xz/1/)

Comment: thanks this works, but what if the selectedGene is coming from a value from the database and I would need a seperate checkbox list for each dropdown to display next to the dropdown. sorry if i wasnt clear in my original post. Here's a link to [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M26xz/4/).

Comment: so do you want to make different different check boxes for each  selectedGene?

Comment: are you able to help with that functionality?

Comment: it is little bit complex then earlier so let me try out first.